# How do I generate a treeView based on remote data using Kendo UI TreeView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I have been reading ALL of the documentation on this and I still cannot get it to work.

I have a Web API which provides a JSON object. It's a list of 22 things. Just 22 lines of text.

I want to take these and form a TreeView. Each of these 22 strings will have items under them but I just want to get the first part working.

My first question is, how do I extract data from an API and populate a treeView with it?

On my main page, I have this:

```
<div id="treeView"></div>
```

On my JavaScript file I have this:

```
$("#treeView").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: true,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://...",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I try to run the page, I get "Request failed." [Retry]

If I open up a browser and go to this URL, data is returned fine as a JSON object.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT -

Code that is returning the JSON:

```
public List<string> getNotificationByUser(int id)
{
      List<string> notificationTitles = new List<string>();

      foreach (var notification in notifications)
      {
          notificationTitles.Add(notification.ToString());
      }
      return notificationTitles;
}
```

Comment: You may want to pull up fiddler and see what's different between the two requests

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out all of my answers:

```
function CreateNotificationTree(userId)
{
    debugger;
    var data = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../api/notifications/byuserid/" + userId,
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "notifications"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: data,
        loadOnDemand: true,
        dataUrlField: "LinksTo",
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataTextField: ["notificationType", "NotificationDesc"],
        select: treeviewSelect
    });

    function treeviewSelect(e)
    {
        var node = this.dataItem(e.node);
        window.open(node.NotificationLink, "_self");
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public List<Node> getNotifications(int id)
{
    var bo = new HomeBO();
    var list = bo.GetNotificationsForUser(id);
    var notificationTreeNodes = (from GBLNotifications n in list
                                 where n.NotificationCount != 0
                                 select new NotificationTreeNode(n)).ToList();
    var li = notificationTreeNodes.Select(no => new Node
    {
            notificationType = no.NotificationNode.NotificationType + " " + "(" + no.NotificationNode.NotificationCount + ")", notifications = bo.GetNotificationsForUser(id, no.NotificationNode.NotificationTypeId).Cast<GBLNotifications>().Select(item => new Notification
            {
                    ID = item.NotificationId, NotificationDesc = item.NotificationDescription, Params = new List<NotificationParam>
                    {
                            new NotificationParam
                            {
                                    ParamName = item.Param1, ParamVal = item.ParamValue1
                            },
                            new NotificationParam
                            {
                                    ParamName = item.Param2, ParamVal = item.ParamValue2
                            },
                            new NotificationParam
                            {
                                    ParamName = item.Param3, ParamVal = item.ParamValue3
                            },
                            new NotificationParam
                            {
                                    ParamName = item.Param4, ParamVal = item.ParamValue4
                            },
                            new NotificationParam
                            {
                                    ParamName = item.Param5, ParamVal = item.ParamValue5
                            },
                    },
                    ActionPageName = item.ActionPageName
            }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
    li.ForEach(i => i.notifications.ForEach(x => x.SetNotificationLink()));
    return li;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I've been able to reproduce your error. The question is that *22 lines of text* are not a valid JSON.

Returning something like:

```
This
is
a
test
```

Is not a valid JSON.

But a valid JSON is not enough, you should return something like this:

```
[
    { "text": "This" },
    { "text": "is" },
    { "text": "a" },
    { "text": "test" }
]
```

I.e.: The result should be an array of objects where each object has a `text` field.

**NOTE** I know that it does not have to be called `text` but for simplicity I used it since it is the default value.

Comment: How do I go about adding the "text" part to the code where I build the list (which is returned as a json?) I updated my OP with the code that is returning the JSON.

Comment: Check this http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html. Click on ASP.NET MVC and then Remote_DataController.cs I hope this helps you.