# Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core TreeView - All nodes labeled 'undefined'

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, treeview, hierarchical-data

I am adding a Kendo TreeView to an ASP Net Core 3.1 Page. All the nodes are 'undefined'. From the picture it is trying to do the 'right' thing. Nesting is correct, expands and contracts correctly.

[Undefined with Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6GBd.png)

I shamelessly used code from [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/navigation/treeview/overview)

My .cshtml

```
    @(
        Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeview")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .TemplateId("treeview-template")
        .DataSource(dataSource1 => dataSource1
            .Custom()
            .Transport(t => t
                .Read(r => r.Url(Url.Page("Index", "Read_TreeViewData")))
            )
        )
    )
```

and .cs

```
        public static IList<HierarchicalViewModel> GetHierarchicalData()
        {
            var result = new List<HierarchicalViewModel>()
            {
                new HierarchicalViewModel() { ID = 1, ParentID = null, HasChildren = true, Name = "Parent item" },
                new HierarchicalViewModel() { ID = 2, ParentID = 1, HasChildren = true, Name = "Parent item" },
                new HierarchicalViewModel() { ID = 3, ParentID = 1, HasChildren = false, Name = "Item" },
                new HierarchicalViewModel() { ID = 4, ParentID = 2, HasChildren = false, Name = "Item" },
                new HierarchicalViewModel() { ID = 5, ParentID = 2, HasChildren = false, Name = "Item" }
            };

            return result;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetRead_TreeViewData(int? id)
        {
            var result = GetHierarchicalData()
                .Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.ParentID == id : x.ParentID == null)
                .Select(item => new {
                    id = item.ID,
                    Name = item.Name,
                    //expanded = item.Expanded,
                    //imageUrl = item.ImageUrl,
                    hasChildren = item.HasChildren
                });

            var jr = new JsonResult(result);
            return jr;
        }
```

I have tried several things, changing the DataTextField, calling .Add() in several places, trying to add a attribute. Does anyone know how to label the nodes with the Name from the HierarchicalViewModel?

Comment: You have TemplateId("treeview-template"). That overrides anything you have set as DataTextField. Do you have it defined on the page? Take that line out for starters and see what the difference is.

Comment: See this link as to how to configure a Kendo TreeView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842222/how-do-i-generate-a-treeview-based-on-remote-data-using-kendo-ui-treeview

Comment: Thanks @NigelK. Commenting out the treeview-template did the trick. If you submit an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have TemplateId("treeview-template") as part of the configuration. A template overrides anything set as DataTextField. The issue is is therefore with the template or the fact that it is missing from the page.

If you simply want the Name property rendered for each node then you can remove the template.